Multiple driver Nets Error for Carry Lookahead Adder
I just began learning SystemVerilog and now am trying to code a Carry Lookahead Adder. However, I kept getting the "Multiple driver Nets" error for the C signal I have.
The error goes like this: [DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net C[0] has multiple drivers: F_OBUF[1]_inst_i_2/O, and F_OBUF[1]_inst_i_3/O.
Here is my top module Adder:
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Adder (
    input wire[3:0] A,
    input wire[3:0] B,
    input wire Cin,
    output wire[3:0] F,
    output wire Cout
    );

    wire[3:0] P, G; // Propagate and Generate signals
    wire[2:0] C;    // Carry signals

    // Generate propagate (P) and generate (G) signals
    assign P = A ^ B;
    assign G = A & B;

    // Generate carry-out signals using carry-lookahead logic
    assign C[0] = G[0] | (P[0] & Cin);
    assign C[1] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | (P[1] & P[0] & Cin);
    assign C[2] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | (P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) | (P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & Cin);

    // Instantiate full adders with carry-lookahead logic
    full_adder adder0 (
        .A(A[0]),
        .B(B[0]),
        .Cin(Cin),
        .F(F[0]),
        .Cout(C[0])
    );

    full_adder adder1 (
        .A(A[1]),
        .B(B[1]),
        .Cin(C[0]),
        .F(F[1]),
        .Cout(C[1])
    );

    full_adder adder2 (
        .A(A[2]),
        .B(B[2]),
        .Cin(C[1]),
        .F(F[2]),
        .Cout(C[2])
    );

    full_adder adder3 (
        .A(A[3]),
        .B(B[3]),
        .Cin(C[2]),
        .F(F[3]),
        .Cout(Cout)
    );

endmodule

And here is the full_adder module:
module full_adder(A, B , Cin, F, Cout);
    input wire A, B, Cin;
    output wire F, Cout;

    assign F = A ^ B ^ Cin;
    assign Cout = (A & B) | (Cin & (A ^ B));
endmodule

I would appreciate any help to solve this error.

Here is one driver of C[0]:
assign C[0] = G[0] | (P[0] & Cin);

The other driver is the Cout output port of full_adder:
    .Cout(C[0])

You must change your code so that C[0] has only one driver.
The same is true for C[1] and C[2].
